# Filtering by value in list

Tags: python, django

Is there any Django filter to do "the opposite" `__in` does?

I have an `Entity` with a `related_entity_set`, and I want to check if **any** of these related entities match with a given `related_entity`. I can do the following to achieve this behavior:

```
Entity.objects.filter(related_entities__in=[related_entity])
```

But it does not look proper. There must be a more straightforward way I am missing right now.

Comment: Can you provide a bit from your models so we can see the relationships?

Comment: @SomeSillyName just a m2m relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It often doesn't look right either, but you can just do:

```
Entity.objects.filter(related_entities=related_entity)
```

given that `related_entities` is either the name or `related_name` of a `ManyToManyField` or the `related_query_name` of a `ForeignKey` (defaulting to the `related_name` if provided or the lowercase model name).